# Combining lists of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to combine list of lists, here is the below sample

```
mylist = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
          [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
```

and the output should be:

```
output = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I also tried using `itertools`, but here is what it returned

```
>>> combined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
>>> combined
>>> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
```

How I can achieve this `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`

Can anyone highlight whats I'm missing?

Comment: do you have only 2 levels of lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot Not exactly a duplicate because in OP's case there are sub lists of sub lists

Comment: try with: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))))`

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the `itertools` method didn't work is because what you have isn't a list of lists, but a list of lists of lists. `itertools` is working properly, its just flattening the list once. Calling the exact same function again with the partially flattened list as an argument will work:

```
flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist)))
```

Or, a simple list comprehension solution:

```
flat = [item for slist in mylist for sslist in slist for item in sslist]
```

This basically translates to:

```
for slist in mylist:
    for sslist in slist:
        for item in sslist:
            flat.append(item)
```

Keep in mind, both these solutions are only good for dealing with double nesting. If there is a chance you will have to deal with even more nesting, I suggest you look up how to flatten arbitrarily nested lists.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you have two levels here so you need two calls to `chain`. But you don't actually need the `from_iterable` call; you can use the `*` syntax instead:

```
list(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*mylist)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With [***numpy.ndarray.flatten()***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [ [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']] ]    
a = np.array(mylist).flatten().tolist()

print(a)
```

The output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```